# Changes to Delegate entries under servive Task for bpmn properties panel not getting updated on UI

Tags: javascript, workflow, camunda, bpmn.io

I'm trying to modify the Details section of General Tab under type Service Task.

**What I want ?**

I'm trying to achieve that when user selects Implementation type as JavaClass I show an dropdown for delegate field instead of an textbox where on any other selection other than JavaClass it shall be textbox.

Later I want to load dynamic data into the dropdown.

**What I tried ?**

I tried the following 2 ways

1 : Edited file [camunda\parts\implementation\Delegate.js](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-properties-panel/blob/354d4ebc845a1e546b91903a7527dc95a1135b8e/lib/provider/camunda/parts/implementation/Delegate.js) to take one more var which stores entryFactory.selectBox and on type == class return the newly created select box in module.exports else return the default textbox.

```
module.exports = function(element, bpmnFactory, options) {

  var getImplementationType = options.getImplementationType,
      getBusinessObject     = options.getBusinessObject;

  var delegateEntrySelect = entryFactory.selectBox({
    id: 'delegate',
     label: 'Value',
    selectOptions: [
      {value:"one",name:"one"},{value:"two",name:"two"}
    ],
    modelProperty: 'delegate',
    emptyParameter: false,

    get: function(element, node) {
      var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
      var type = getImplementationType(element);
      var attr = getAttribute(type);
      var label = getDelegationLabel(type);
      return {
        delegate: bo.get(attr),
        delegationLabel: label
      };
    },

    set: function(element, values, node) {
      var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
      var prop = {};
      prop[attr] = values.delegate || '';
      return cmdHelper.updateBusinessObject(element, bo, prop);
    },

    validate: function(element, values, node) {
      return isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && !values.delegate ? { delegate: 'Must provide a value' } : {};
    }
  });   

  var delegateEntry = entryFactory.textField({
    id: 'delegate',
    label: 'Value',
    dataValueLabel: 'delegationLabel',
    modelProperty: 'delegate',

    get: function(element, node) {
      var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
      var type = getImplementationType(element);
      var attr = getAttribute(type);
      var label = getDelegationLabel(type);
      return {
        delegate: bo.get(attr),
        delegationLabel: label
      };
    },

    set: function(element, values, node) {
      var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
      var type = getImplementationType(element);
      var attr = getAttribute(type);
      var prop = {};
      prop[attr] = values.delegate || '';
      return cmdHelper.updateBusinessObject(element, bo, prop);
    },

    validate: function(element, values, node) {
      return isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && !values.delegate ? { delegate: 'Must provide a value' } : {};
    }
  });

  var eleTOReturn = (getImplementationType(element) && getImplementationType(element) == "class") ? delegateEntrySelect : delegateEntry
  console.log("returning ele",eleTOReturn)
  return [ eleTOReturn ];
};
```

What I get in output is:

[image]

2 : Passed both selectBox and default text box but differentiated them in disabled by condition such as 
a : selectBox (!isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) || (isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && type !== "class"))

b : textBox (!isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) || (isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && type === "class"))

In both the cases the JS code executes well and the same can be seen under group.entries variable inside [camunda\parts\serviceTaskDelegateProps.js](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-properties-panel/blob/354d4ebc845a1e546b91903a7527dc95a1135b8e/lib/provider/camunda/parts/ServiceTaskDelegateProps.js) line#60 but they don't get reflected on UI.

The Delegate.js code is as under

```
module.exports = function(element, bpmnFactory, options) {

var getImplementationType = options.getImplementationType,
  getBusinessObject     = options.getBusinessObject;

var delegateEntrySelect = entryFactory.selectBox({
id: 'delegate',
 label: 'Value',
selectOptions: [
  {value:"one",name:"one"},{value:"two",name:"two"}
],
modelProperty: 'delegate',
emptyParameter: false,

get: function(element, node) {
  var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
  var type = getImplementationType(element);
  var attr = getAttribute(type);
  var label = getDelegationLabel(type);
  return {
    delegate: bo.get(attr),
    delegationLabel: label
  };
},

set: function(element, values, node) {
  var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
  var prop = {};
  prop[attr] = values.delegate || '';
  return cmdHelper.updateBusinessObject(element, bo, prop);
},

validate: function(element, values, node) {
  return isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && !values.delegate ? { delegate: 'Must provide a value' } : {};
},

disabled: function(element, node) {
  var type = getImplementationType(element);
  console.log("SELECT DISABLE",(!isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) || (isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && type !== "class")))
  return (!isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) || (isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && type !== "class"));
}
});   

var delegateEntry = entryFactory.textField({
id: 'delegate',
label: 'Value',
dataValueLabel: 'delegationLabel',
modelProperty: 'delegate',

get: function(element, node) {
  var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
  var type = getImplementationType(element);
  var attr = getAttribute(type);
  var label = getDelegationLabel(type);
  return {
    delegate: bo.get(attr),
    delegationLabel: label
  };
},

set: function(element, values, node) {
  var bo = getBusinessObject(element);
  var type = getImplementationType(element);
  var attr = getAttribute(type);
  var prop = {};
  prop[attr] = values.delegate || '';
  return cmdHelper.updateBusinessObject(element, bo, prop);
},

validate: function(element, values, node) {
  return isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && !values.delegate ? { delegate: 'Must provide a value' } : {};
},

disabled: function(element, node) {
  var type = getImplementationType(element);
  console.log("TEXT DISABLE",(!isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) || (isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && type === "class")))
  return (!isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) || (isDelegate(getImplementationType(element)) && type === "class")); 
}  
});

 return [ delegateEntrySelect, delegateEntry ];
};
```

What I get in output is

[image]

Can Someone please help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding a different file for Select Box as delegateSelect.js adjacent to delegate.js and then in serviceTaskDelegateProps.js registered it as

```
group.entries = group.entries.concat(delegateSelect(element, bpmnFactory, {
    getBusinessObject: getBusinessObject,
    getImplementationType: getImplementationType,
    hideDelegateSelect: function(element, node) {
      console.log(getImplementationType(element) !== 'class',"SELECT")
      return getImplementationType(element) !== 'class';
    }
   }));

  group.entries = group.entries.concat(delegate(element, bpmnFactory, {
    getBusinessObject: getBusinessObject,
    getImplementationType: getImplementationType,
    hideDelegateText: function(element, node) {
      console.log(getImplementationType(element) === 'class',"TEXT")
      return getImplementationType(element) === 'class';
    }
  }));
```

and in respective delegate and delegateSelect handled the disabled as

```
 disabled: function(element, node) {
      if (typeof hideDelegateText === 'function') {
        return hideDelegateText.apply(delegateEntry, arguments);
      }
    }

disabled: function(element, node) {
      if (typeof hideDelegateSelect === 'function') {
        return hideDelegateSelect.apply(delegateEntrySelect, arguments);
      }
    }
```

I referred the [ResultVariable.js](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-properties-panel/blob/354d4ebc845a1e546b91903a7527dc95a1135b8e/lib/provider/camunda/parts/implementation/ResultVariable.js) file to reach this solution

For a detailed view got to [Camunda-blog](https://blog.camunda.org/post/2017/04/adding-custom-elements-to-bpmn-properties-panel/)
Thanks